# html force rerender div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have flex row with max-height.
wrapper of image have min-height:0; property for block height overflow;

but after load image and shrink we see that wrapper of image is not recomputer has extra spaced (red rectangle).
How i can recomputed div to shrink to image width?

[image]

```
<div class="flex max-h-[300px] justify-start bg-purple-500">

    <div class="flex min-h-0 border-[5px] border-red-700">
      <img class="block w-auto mx-auto border-2 border-green-700" src="https://wallpapershome.ru/images/pages/pic_v/14572.jpg"/>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

sandbox
https://play.tailwindcss.com/td171IEWi6

Comment: `width: min-content;`?

Comment: dont work , all shrink ro 0 :D https://play.tailwindcss.com/imH4d0g0O5

Comment: In IMG tag instead of w-auto use w-100. <img class="block w-100"

Comment: @Mehrwarz dont work https://play.tailwindcss.com/nP06OSzWLS  we asked to remove the voids, and you filled them for us :D and lose image aspectrate

Comment: Sorry Padavano! My English is not good, somehow the CSS you are using is not responding to WIDTH: MAX-CONTENT.

Answer (score 0):

Defin a new class and add it to the IMG parrent tage(Border-red). or you can use same class name if you want to ovver-write the defaults.

```
.border-red-700{
        border: red 5px solid;
        width: max-content;
        position:relative;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

also change the image height equal to the DIV tag height (300px);

```
<img class="block w-auto mx-auto border-2 border-green-700 max-h-[280px]" src="https://wallpapershome.ru/images/pages/pic_v/14572.jpg"/>
```